# Help me to solve this question! It's about figuring out the area by using integration

Tags: integration

[image]
[image: This is what i tried !]

My book said "Use integral 2 pi x ds but I have no idea about ds. Help me to solve this !

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. As a general courtesy, you should show us that you've made at least some attempt at answering the question yourself. Could you show us that?

Comment: I added my solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $s$ is often used for arc length. If you imagine moving along a curve by a very tiny amount $(dx,dy)$, then you are approximately moving along the hypotenuse $ds$ of a triangle with base $dx$ and height $dy$. Then $ds^2 = dx^2+dy^2$, so we write
$$ds = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = \sqrt{1 + \left(\tfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\;\;dx$$
or
$$ds = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = \sqrt{\left(\tfrac{dx}{dy}\right)^2 + 1}\;\;dy$$
as appropriate.

This is all really mnemonic to help you remember the formula. Such approximations are really done using $\Delta y$ and $\Delta x$ then passing to the limit with an actual sum, so you get an integral.

Comment: Can you teach me what is the problem on my solution? I just added my solution on this post